Неправильно записывается строка в языке С
Вот моя функция для добавления нового студента в "базу данных".
int Add(Student* database, int count) {
    struct Student student;

    puts("\nВведите ID студента: ");
    scanf("%du", &database[count].ID);

    fflush(stdin);
    puts("\nВведите ФИО студента: ");
    scanf("%s", &database[count].FIO);
    fflush(stdin);

    char sex;
    puts("\nВведите пол студента( М или Ж ): ");
    scanf(" %c", &sex);
    student.sex = sex;


    int groupNumber;
    printf("\nВ какую группу студент зачислен? (1, 2 или 3)\n\nВаш выбор: ");
    scanf("%d", &groupNumber);
    student.groupNumber = groupNumber;

    database[count] = student;
    count++;
    return count;
}

Проблема в следующем: Когда ввожу ФИО, неважно на каком языке, вместо строки записывается "ММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММ". Перепробовала много всего, но ничего не помогает.
Прикладываю структуру на всякий случай:
struct Student {
    int ID;
    char FIO[100];
    char sex;
    int groupNumber;
};


Ну кода записи же тут нет. На экран пробовали выводить что ввелось?

Вы сперва считали имя в переменную - часть массива: database[count] , а потом затерли: database[count] = student;

@Chorkov О, точно. Часть в поля читается по индексу элемента в базе, а часть в student, мешанина какая-то. Ну и потом второе кладётся в базу, да.

Учтите еще, что в scanf("%s", &database[count].FIO); тут из всего ввода вносится только одно слово, а остальной ввод идет в следующие чтения...

В структуре struct Student элемент char FIO[100] является указателем на char, таким образом, в
scanf("%s", &database[count].FIO);

вы берете указатель на указатель. Поэтому достаточно указать
scanf("%s", database[count].FIO);

Отвечая на вопрос, почему в этом поле лежат одни буквы "М", скорее всего это происходит из-за того, что память под "базу данных" вы выделяете с помощью malloc(), который никак не санитизирует выделенную память. Чтобы в дальнейшем избегать проблем с "мусором", который может лежать на куче, старайтесь занулять полученный участок памяти:
struct Student *s = (struct Student *)malloc(nStudents * sizeof(struct Student));
memset(s, 0, nStudents * sizeof(struct Student));

либо
struct Student *s = (struct Student *)calloc(nStudents, sizeof(struct Student));

